# Error trying to install Ubuntu with portable USB stick

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, kernel

**!!! Problem report after "Background" section. !!!**

---

***Background***

Recently my dad gave to me is pc (since mine was having some problems with the hardware, and since he is a bit old he was getting very slow).
The computer had previous problems, (after entering the password he would just froze).
My father told me that my brother installed something in the computer and he never worked again.
Fastforward I did a reset after a lot of struggle, and since the computer was having lot of issues to get into safe mode, during the reset operation(froze) and installing windows OS(also froze).

*At the moment I already did the reset, windows is already installed and I also created a partition with ~100GB.*

---

***Problem:***

So after these, I wanted to install Ubuntu.
I downloaded ubuntu 21.10 and I created a bootable USB stick with BalenaEtcher.
I had some problems finding my bootable USB stick in the boot menu, so I did the following:

*BIOS version : 304*

- disabled "fast boot"
- disabled "secure boot"
- enabled "CSM support"
- enable "Lauch PXE opROM policy"
- made my bootable USB stick "Boot Option #1"

---

GNU GRUB version 2.04

*After I saved and exit, I got the following menu:*

> - *Ubuntu
> - Ubuntu (safe graphics)
> - OEM install (for manufacters)
> - Test memory

---

*After choosing the first option, I had the following errors:*

> error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'
>
> error : you need to load the kernel first
>
> Press any key to continue...

---

*Listed disk and the partitions on command-line :*

> grub> ls
>
> (hd0)

---

I don't know what to do, I searched for similar cases and some solutions but I didn't make any progress.
Any sugestion/help will be well received, I will keep trying to find the solution and I'll update as soon as I get a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you verify your ISO (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) and then verify the write of your ISO to your installation media?  (*Ubuntu 21.10 I now note in question self-validates; I'd perform this on another box where it'll likely fail as well; confirming a likely bad write to media*).   The out-of-disk error can occur because of partition table issue on machine OR invalid media (which is sending the disk outside of valid area...) so I'd verify your write of ISO to your media.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes making your bootable USB-stick/SD-card doesn't go well. So verify your written USB, like @guiverc suggested. If Balena doesn't work try Rufus or Ventoy. Personally I have bad experiences with Ubuntu based systems and Balena and when I used Rufus all problems I encountered disappeared.